# angular-translate case insensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) to translate given identifiers.

Identifier list:

```
{
  'UserName': 'Benutzername',
  'EmailAddress': 'E-mail Adresse'
}
```

In the View im using the translate filter:

```
<p>{{ 'UserName' | translate }}</p>
```

Is there a way to tell the translate filter to match case insensetive:

```
<p>{{ 'username' | translate }}</p>
<p>{{ 'UsErNaMe' | translate }}</P>
```

**Edit:**

This is for a larger project, so it isn't an option to just lowercase all identifiers and put them through an additional filter like `{{ 'UseRnAme' | lowercase | translate }}` because this means adjusting every single line in the html code. The translate directive is also used at some places `<p translate>UsErNamE</p>`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is, if you know what case your translation keys are in, you can  work around the problem if the keys and the identifiers used match a few requirements.

It would be easiest if your translation keys are all UPPERCASE or all lowercase with no underscores or hyphens. If this is the case you can wrap the translation service with your own directive that will change the case of the keys.

If the translation keys are PascalCase, then you will be able to normalize directive identifiers that are camelCase or SNAKE_CASE or kabab-case to PascalCase. You would NOT be able to normalize ALLUPPERCASE or alllowercase to PascalCase.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @Martin's answer , if you do decide to have your translation literals in a single case , you can add filters to pass the value further to the translate directive.Like this :

```
<p>{{ 'username'| uppercase/lowercase | translate }}</p>
<p>{{ 'UsErNaMe'| uppercase/lowercase | translate }}</P>
```

Comment: You can use any of filter but for that you will have to keep identifier list in same case only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, (Usage of translate filter irrespective of case sensitive and spaces between the text)

Step 1 : Define a custom filter to translate the text in controller :

```
      app.register.filter('translated', ['$translate', function ($translate) {
    return function (text) {
        return $translate.instant(text.replace(/\s/g,'').toUpperCase()); 
    };
}]);
```

Step 2 : Use the custom filter 'translated' instead of 'translate',

```
            <p>{{ 'username' | translated}}</p>
            <p>{{ 'UsErNaMe' | translated}}</p>
            <p>{{ 'User Name' | translated}}</p>
            <p>{{ 'User    Name' | translated}}</p>
```

Step 3 : In translation

```
          {
               'USERNAME': 'Benutzername',
               'EmailAddress': 'E-mail Adresse'
          }
```

Hope, it is useful.